# How to position figcaption under the image

Tags: html, css, image, css-position, figure

I am trying to position my figcaption under the img. 
I don't know why does it go to the right. I have other images on the page and their figcaption doesn't go to the right, it's under the image, but on this one it's not under and it should be. Can somebody help me?

Here is my section of HTML code:

```css
 figure{
        margin: 0;
    }

    #fig_moje_slike{
        font-size: 9px;
        text-align: left;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #sadrzaj{
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 3em auto;
    }

    #sadrzaj ul{
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }

    #sadrzaj ul li{
        margin: 15px 0;
    }

    #slika_mene{
        width: 14%;
        height: auto;
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
<section id="sadrzaj">
            <aside>
                <figure>
                    <img src="slike/ja.jpeg" alt="slika mene" id="slika_mene">
                    <figcaption id="fig_moje_slike">Moja slika</figcaption> 
                </figure>
            </aside>
            <ul>
                <li>bla bla</li>
                <li>bla bla</li>
                <li>bla bal</li>
                <li>blabla</li>
            </ul>
        </section>
```

Picture of result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYOfD.jpg

Comment: i have answered below. It seems your question isn't clear enough. please remember to ask the question as clear as possible. how you want the result and what is problem, everything should be mentioned as much as possible. however, check the answer I've provided, i hope that will work for you

Comment: @Lucian, I think, from reading some of his comments below, he needs the `aside` element on the left and the `ul` element on the right side but he's floating both `#slika_mene` and `ul` to the left. There is a simple solution with `display: flex` as well as with floats to his problem. Unfortunately, he did not state his desired outcome clearly.

Comment: @Mers yeah, that's right. I also figured that out reading few of his comments so I answered accordingly

Comment: Yes, sorry guys for a bit unclear question, I forgot to mention that I needed a result as Mers said. I marked @Lucian solution as the best one because it requires minimum changes to the HTML and CSS. Thanks to all who wanted to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `float: left` from `img` and `figcaption` tag. instead use `float` for `aside` and as per `width`, use it on `aside`

https://jsfiddle.net/Ls6coLb7/3/ here is the updated fiddle

Comment: Please check the updated fiddle. I've commented the changes

Answer (score 0):

`#slika_mene` put a `float:left`. this a misstake. give `float:left` to `figure`.

```css
figure {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

#fig_moje_slike {
  font-size: 9px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
}

#sadrzaj {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3em auto;
}

#sadrzaj ul {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

#sadrzaj ul li {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

#slika_mene {
  width: 14%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  /*
  float: left;
*/
}
```

```html
<section id="sadrzaj">
  <aside>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://beerhold.it/600/600" alt="slika mene" id="slika_mene">
      <figcaption id="fig_moje_slike">Moja slika</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </aside>
  <ul>
    <li>bla bla</li>
    <li>bla bla</li>
    <li>bla bal</li>
    <li>blabla</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: When I do that, my <li> items go underneath the picture and they should be on the right next to the image, how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

you put a `float:left` on slika_mene. So if you delete this property it's go under your img

Answer (score 0):

I got it just use `clear:left;` on `#fig_moje_slike` id
like this

```
#fig_moje_slike{
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    clear:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't need to syle picture, and you should not, because after that, if you change it, you have to style it again, so its better to style `<figure>`, you dont need to use `float` at all, remove `id` from the picture and add style to `figure`

this is example, put `width` to whatever you want

and add this to `img` tag

```
figure{
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left:100px;
}
img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove clear:left from #fig_moje_slike

HTML:

```
        <figure>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" alt="slika mene" id="slika_mene">
            <figcaption id="fig_moje_slike">Moja slika</figcaption> 
        </figure>
```

CSS:

```
#fig_moje_slike{
font-size: 9px;
text-align: left;
width: 50%;
margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `clear:left;` on `#fig_moje_slike` id I think it will works